# inverse of a smooth function in R

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Does a $C^1$ strictly increasing function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ admit an inverse which is also $C^1$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Consider the function $f(x) = x^3$.